# How should I hook up this phone jack?

Tags: wire, telephone

By accident I pulled the little outlet out of the wall and the wires came out. I remember the electric guy once did it, and put only these 2 wires in, but somehow i'm not getting any phone signal...

I'm not sure i've put these 2 cables back as they were. Though I remember it only having 2 cables... (ps this is the back view of a telephone outlet thingy thats in the wall)

[image]

Comment: Is this in Europe or in North America?  Or elsewhere?  Wire colors vary by country.

Comment: @DwayneReid Thailand based on his website country code of .th

Comment: Do you have another jack anywhere in your home? If so, open it up (carefully!) to see how it's wired, and wire your broken jack to match.

Comment: unfortunately I don't... I'll see if i can get a look at the neighbours  one :)

Answer (score 1):

These Jacks can be difficult and are often a one time install product. The wire may not simply have 'pulled out' from it, the copper conductor may have actually broken off inside the unit OR the tabs that make contact with the conductors could be broken inside.

Even if you able to push in newly stripped wires and have them 'grab tight' and stay mechanically connected, there may be conductors inside the jack that do create a closed circuit.

You'll spend far less time and energy replacing with new, than troubleshooting and/or repairing these mass produced units.

Good luck. Let us know if you have a solution.

Comment: That makes sense.. I'm pretty sure there were only 2 wires in it, which were the 2 on the image, as the other 2 were taped together and tugged away. I've been trying all combo's... I'll ee if i can get a new one, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a voltmeter?  If so, you should get a DC voltage across two of the wires (in the US, it is around 48v with all phones on-hook).  Once you have identified the two wires with a DC voltage, they should be put into your connector, I would guess either as you show in the picture, or in the other two holes (i.e. they would not be wired diagonally).

If you don't have a voltmeter, I would try the six combinations of the four colors, picking up the phone each time and seeing if you have dialtone.

Once you have dialtone using either method, trying tone dialing.  If you don't hear a tone, reverse the wires.  (Most modern phones don't care anymore, but older ones were polarity sensitive.)